# Call external JS files in Angular 12

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

How to Call external JS files in Angular, try to add Datepicker JS in angular https://github.com/balbarak/bootstrap-hijri-datepicker

```
import $ from "jquery";
import  "../../../../../../assets/js/bootstrap-hijri-datetimepicker.js";

  DatePicker() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#hijri-picker").hijriDatePicker({
        hijri: true,
        showSwitcher: false,
      });
    });
  }
 <input id="hijri-picker" (click)="DatePicker()" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

I  am getting fn.hijriDatePicker is not a function, how to call date picker on click https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1pqfr5?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: You can add external file as NPM dependency and then just use it like normal module

Comment: Added in package i don't know  how to call

Comment: You need to add required script tag in index.html. Have you done it ?

Comment: Yes added     <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-hijri-datetimepicker.js"></script>

Comment: Use developer tool and check sources, if this js is getting load or not. I think its better to create a stackblitz demo for better debugging.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: _assets_js_bootstrap_hijri_datetimepicker_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.fn.hijriDatePicker is not a function

Comment: try adding import like `import  * from "bootstrap-hijri-datetimepicker.js";` after installing it via npm.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1pqfr5?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @cloned Cannot find module 'bootstrap-hijri-datetimepicker.js' or its corresponding type declarations.

Comment: You should include the javascript function in a external Javascript file and locate in assets folder. Then add the path in Angular json scripts list. Then use onClick event in your angular html and call the function. jQuery should not be use in Angular component. Hope It will resolve your issue. Thank you:)

Comment: It can't find it because the package is called without `.js` at the end. You put the same name there that you use when installing a package (that's what the error tells you)